# MapKit crashes - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to add pin/address annotations in my Google maps view. When I do this everyting works fine:

```
[self addPin: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng) title: @"test" subtitle: @"test"];
```

with:

```
- (void) addPin: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) position title: (NSString *) pinTitle subtitle: (NSString *) pinSubtitle{

AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:pinTitle andCoordinate:position andSubtitle:pinSubtitle];

[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
[addAnnotation autorelease];

}
```

and

```
#import "AddressAnnotation.h"

@implementation AddressAnnotation

@synthesize title, coordinate, subtitle;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andSubtitle:(NSString *)sbtitle {
[super init];
title = ttl;
coordinate = c2d;
subtitle = sbtitle;
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
[title release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

with:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

NSString *title;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andSubtitle:(NSString *)sbtitle;

@end
```

things go wrong when I do this:

```
NSString *detailTitle   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [key objectForKey:@"name"]];
NSString *detailSubtitle    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [key objectForKey:@"vicinity"]];

 NSLog(@"%@", detailSubtitle);
[self addPin: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng) title: detailTitle subtitle: detailSubtitle];
```

The app chrases somethimes when the pins are supposed to go in my view and somethimes this error:

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5851c80'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `init` function from `AddressAnnotation.m` to

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andSubtitle:(NSString *)sbtitle {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.title = ttl;
        self.coordinate = c2d;
        self.subtitle = sbtitle;
    }
    return self;
}
```

You are using the instance variables directly to set the values in the class instance and not the properties so the actual values that you pass are not copied hence not retained.

Comment: thnx, that works, except for the self.coordinate. That one need to stay without the self. otherwise it gives an error. Can you try to explain again why I need to do this, to be honest I dont get it. Is it because the coordinate isn't an pointer, and the title and subtitle are ?

Comment: No. When you create a @property in your h file and later use @ synthesize you actually let the compiler to build the setter and getter functions for that instance variable for you. When you use self.variableName it's like calling `[self setVariableName:newValue]` which in your case would do `[variableName release]; variableName = [newValue copy];`. Hope that makes sense. If not you can try reading [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial).

Comment: @user706933 @Mihai Fratu Bear in mind that [Apple discourages the usage of accessor methods in initializers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Answer (score 0):

NSCFNumber is one of the private implementations of NSNumber. NSNumber does not have a method called length, so it does not recognize the selector. So far so good.

It is hard to tell where this NSNumber is being used. ISTM that the problem is not in your code. I don't know enough of MapKit to give you a workaround.